# iPhone app that talks to the server

Tags: php, ios, ruby-on-rails, api, parse-platform

I need to build an iphone app that talks to a website. Logins, fetching data etc.
I have built few apps that does these using website's api but the website I'm working with now does not have one. I don't have enough knowledge of PHP or RoR so I'm not sure if I could build a back-end API from scratch and then start on the ios development.

I did some research and it looked like there are websites like parse.com or appactive where they help you with back-end api. Though, I looked around the website and read the about page but I'm still not sure how they work. Could those services help me if I already have a server/website running and I need an app that requires login and data exchanges?

Comment: simply use Parse.com these days.  couldn't be easier.  throw away your existing backend and just do that.  you CAN make server calls, from parse cloud code, to your existing server to get data etc. so yes that's possible. but what a chore.

Comment: Yes there are many APIs that can help you that way like Parse(you said), QuickBlox etc. They let you setup your project with their API

Comment: channi, parse does not let you add an API to some existing server.  however, it can connect to an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jus a note, in 2016 Parse has closed (it's now open source and you run it on Heroku or whatever). There are many other "baas" such as Firebase etc.

---

Since there seems to be some confusion,

(a) your current service has no API. it is, thus, unfortunately essentially useless so your most absolutely time saving step from here would be just scrap it and use parse (or another baas) as the backend.  you can have parse up and running in minutes. what previously took server developers man-years is now just like "a consumer product", just make a few clicks to add column-names

(b) your current service has no API. assuming yo DO WANT TO continue to use it, you will have to somehow add an API, using php or whatever.  there's no way to avoid this.  IF you do that, then you could (if you wanted) make a "basic" API that parse can get the info from, and then use parse to actually connect to the ios/android builds (since that is so easy)

TBC, here's literally how you do that in Parse,

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking

"Cloud Code allows sending HTTP requests to any HTTP Server" it's that simple.

As I mention above, it's far easier just to scratch your current backend and change to a bAAs (such as Parse). you have to "go with the times" you know?

Note that the development and testing of an API on a service is incedibly time consuming, it is a huge job for a team.

Here on this question you seem to be asking about bAAs and how they fit in the formula.  the answers are:

(1) if you simply scrap your current service, do everything on a baas: it is trivial. what used to take literally man-years is now a few clicks

(2) in terms of "helping you ADD AN API to that service".  bAAs cannot help you with that in any way and is irrelevant

(3) if you DO have a service with an API, yes it is relatively easy to have bAAs "link in" to that. (i include literally the doco from pare on doing that above)

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: The question is specific to existing web apps without an external API. What good is Parse sending HTTP requests to an API that doesn't exist?

Comment: **"Though, I looked around the website and read the about page but I'm still not sure how they work. Could those services help me if I already have a server/website running and I need an app that requires login and data exchanges?"**

Comment: of course, obviously, he will have to add an API to the existing service site.  (he'll have to do that "no matter what".)  OR, the best idea is just junk the current server (a service with no API is useless) and just use Parse, which is unbelievably easy.

Comment: Not sure how implementing an API is a huge, time-consuming job, yet **rewriting a live web application from scratch and migrating accounts and data to another platform** is "unbelievably easy." Such speculation is neither helpful nor realistic.

Comment: bAAs are "unbelievably easy", i.e. you can often do in literally a day, what previously took 6-24 man-months.  the amount of stuff "built in and already working" in bAAs is ... unbelievable.  After all, this is the very nature of software.  It is "unbelievably easy" to use an SQL database, rather than having to roll your own as before their arrival.  regarding implementing an API on an existing service, even in the simplest situation it will take weeks of back and fore and testing.  (I am not aware of any packages, etc, that make "building an API tremendously easier.)

Comment: Thank you Joe. Now I understand what those services actually provide and what I have to do.